# Multiples Request Guzzle

Tags: laravel, guzzle

Pongo en contexto, tengo 1 API de Ofertas y otra API con los detalles de las mismas.
En las ofertas pongo el código postal y me devuelve un json con todas las ofertas determinadas de ese código postal con una información mínima.

XXXXXX.com/Ofertas/1234

Ej, me devuelve la oferta 9874, 6357 y 1897

Ahora, yo necesito los detalles de esas ofertas también y están en otro endpoint

XXXXXX.com/Detalle/9874
XXXXXX.com/Detalle/6357
XXXXXX.com/Detalle/1897

Respectivamente.

En mi controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
$client = new Client();
        
               
                $promise = $client->requestAsync(
                    'GET',
                    'XXXXXX.com/Detalle/'.$result['id'].''
                );

$promise2 = $client->requestAsync(
                    'GET',
                    'XXXXXX.com/Detalle/'.$result['id'].''
                );
$promise3 = $client->requestAsync(
                    'GET',
                    'XXXXXX.com/Detalle/1897'
                );
                
                
                $promises = [$promise, $promise2, , $promise3];
        
                $results = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\settle($promises)->wait();
        
                foreach($results as $result){
                    echo $result['value']->getBody();
                }
                return $results;
```

Esto me esta funcionando bien pero necesito hacer algo asi como esto:

```
$client = new Client();
    
            foreach($results['resultadoComparador'] as $result)
            {
            $promise = $client->requestAsync(
                'GET',
                'XXXXXX.com/Detalle/'.$result['id'].''
            );
            }
            
            $promises = [$promise];
    
            $results = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\settle($promises)->wait();
    
            foreach($results as $result){
                echo $result['value']->getBody();
            }
            return $results;
```

este igualmente funciona pero en $promises = [$promise]; solamente me envia el ultimo ID del foreach y no por ejemplo $promise1, $promise2, $promise3.

Alguien podría decirme como solucionar esto?

Actualmente lo tenía funcionando con un foreach en las ofertas, obviamente esto para pruebas me funciona pero para producción no ya que me devuelve mas de 20 o 30 ofertas y mi foreach estaba buscando 1 detalle de oferta a la vez... y correrlo con 20 o 30 ofertas tarda una eternidad.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, había olvidado colocar los [] delante de $promise para hacerlo array.

```
foreach($results['resultadoComparador'] as $result)
        {
        $promise[] = $client->requestAsync(
            'GET',
            'XXXXXX.com/Detalle/'.$result['id'].''
        );

        }


        $promises = $promise;
```